# How to select values from one column of a table and insert those values randomly in rows of another table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table as "tbl_passwords" where I am storing 'sno' & 'password'. I want to select values from 'password' column and Insert the values in "hw_passwords" as rows and that too randomly.

Below is the screenshot of "tbl_passwords"

[image]

Following screenshot for "hw_passwords"

[image]

I hope the question is clear. I have googled many times but not finding any right way to do it. Your help will be appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is ther any relation between two table?

Comment: no there is no relation between two tables

Comment: Normalise your schema

Comment: i didn't get you @Strawberry

Comment: With Google's assistance, see if you can work out what I mean

Answer (score -1):

```
INSERT INTO `hw_passwords`
(`email`, `password1`, `password2`, `password3`, `password4`, `password5`),
VALUES
(
$email ,
SELECT password FROM tbl_passwords ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1),
SELECT password FROM tbl_passwords ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1),
SELECT password FROM tbl_passwords ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1),
SELECT password FROM tbl_passwords ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1),
SELECT password FROM tbl_passwords ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1)
);
```

If you want to insert unique password in every column then you have to use procudure

Answer (score -1):

```
INSERT INTO tbl_password( sno,email,password1,password2,password3,password4,password5) 
VALUES (NULL ,  'test@mail.com', 

(SELECT PASSWORD FROM user_password
ORDER BY RAND( ) 
LIMIT 1
), 
(SELECT PASSWORD FROM user_password
    ORDER BY RAND( ) 
    LIMIT 1
    ), 
(SELECT PASSWORD FROM user_password
    ORDER BY RAND( ) 
    LIMIT 1
    ), 
(SELECT PASSWORD FROM user_password
    ORDER BY RAND( ) 
    LIMIT 1
    ), 
(SELECT PASSWORD FROM user_password
    ORDER BY RAND( ) 
    LIMIT 1
    )
    )
```

This code is working as exactly how i need. Thanks for your comments guys.